# ASP.Net Application losing credentials after a few seconds

Tags: asp.net, dns

I have an asp.net application that appears to be losing its credentials in one environment (DEV...of course), but not another (INT).
After logging in, and clicking around randomly for a few seconds, I am eventually redirected back to the login page.

I'm not a network admin, so please forgive me if I say something incorrectly.
In short, there are two environments: DEV and INT. 
Each has a DNS A record that points to an underlying server.
In DEV, The URL the app points to is something like devEnv.organization.com.  This points to a server named dev01.
In INT, the URL the app points to is something like intEnv.organization.com.  This points to two server: int01 and int02.  Right now, the network admin did something to take int02 out of the picture, so the intEnv.organization.com record just points to 01.
The issue described above manifests in this environment.
If we point the application directly to the int01 server, the application works just fine.

Again, in DEV, the application works perfectly (naturally) regardless if we point to the devEnv.organization.com URL or the dev01 server.
Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing this or ways to troubleshoot this?
The client is using IIS7.
The web.config is the same on each (except for the database connection string which points to the appropriate database server.)

Please help!

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Is it really random or is it happening on specific links? My guess is that you have a hard-coded link somewhere that is sending you to a different server with a different machine key.

Comment: The links that we are clicking on is in a grid that is populated from a database call.  So the link is not hard coded.

Comment: ^^ re: OP's reply to Nathan's comment: but are you absolutely sure that the links in the database are all relative links. If one of those database links pointed to the same app on a different domain, you would appear to be logged out (but in fact would have never logged in).

Answer (score 0):

I would just sniff the traffic with an http debugger like Fiddler. Eventually, you will be signed out. Then you go back to Fiddler and inspect the very last request. What you search is the header that clears out the authentication cookie. Or any other cause that forces your browser to stop to attach the cookie to consecutive requests.

Edit:

Run Fiddler. You will see a list of requests. On the right, you can see each request details. Request at the top, response at the bottom. Switch to Raw View. What you search for is the Set-Cookie line in the header section if the response (first few lines). One of first requests will SET the forms authentication cookie - assign the name and the value. You just have to find the forms cookie among other cookies. Few requests later you will probably see that the cookie is set again but this time with a date pointing to the past. This CLEARS the cookie and you are signed out.

What you have to find out is WHY it happens, i.e. what causes the particular page to clear the cookie.

If you first want to learn Fiddler, google for "Fiddler tutorial", there are plenty.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for this.  Never had to sniff network traffic before...is it smelly?  :-)  seriously, Is there a website or article you can point me to that I can read to learn how to interpret the traffic?  For example, when you say "search for the header that clears out the authentication cookie..." I wouldn't know what it looks like (and I doubt it will say "clear auth cookie..."). Anything you can point me to would be appreciated.